# One application pool keeps hanging IIS 7

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

For some reason my application pool keeps crashing once in a couple of days. The biggest problem is that there are no logs about errors or warnings in my administrative events about this pool. (there are several warnings in other pools, but it is only this pool that keeps crashing). Changes I make can only be tested if they worked if I wait a couple of days.

I tried to bring my code back to the stage where the problems did not occur, but this does not seem to help.

Most crashes happen when the site is not very busy, although not that inactive that IIS shuts it down for inactivity.

Windows server 2008 R2 (SP 1),
IIS Build 7.5.76,
Umbraco,
Sql server 2008

IIS logs: only showing some recycling of the pool (once every 3 hours)
Rapid fail detection: disabled

Where should I start with solving this problem?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the IIS logs?

Comment: Have you checked EventViewer?

Comment: IIS log is only showing recycling of pool. With eventviewer you mean my administrative events?  The memory my app is using is not big and does not rise. Does that exclude a memory leak? Or should I check in a different way?

Comment: Anything under the "System" event log (Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer)?

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach is to start making trace log files. Write detailed log messages at every critical point in your application - when the request starts, when it ends, somewhere in the middle, when doing DB operations, etc. The logfiles will probably take up gigabytes at the end of the day, but you can afford that for a little while. Then, when it crashes again, check the logfile to see what was the last thing it was doing before the crash. If there's not enough detail, add more logging and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

WER (Windows Error Reporting) should have made crash dumps for you unless disabled. The default location for the crash reports is c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\ , but as far as I can remember, the Windows event log entry for the crash contains the full path for the dump file (Application event log). Pop it into your VS and check what went wrong.

You can also try installing DebugDiag, but personally I highly do NOT recommend it on a production server as it screws up the WER configuration for its own purposes in an unreversible way affecting other applications too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by running the risk application on a different application pool to minimize the impact.
There is an iss property which stops the app pool from rebooting after 5 errors occur in x minutes. 
You could try increasing this setting, it should give you an idea to how frequent this is happening and if it goes wrong once it'll keep going wrong or not.
If it's a wcf service you can enable tracing logs(which log quite a lot , maybe even your error).
As for places to look i would recommend checking out stack overflows and multi threaded code.
 Both of these can cause situations in which the event log will contain no information.

Comment: Thanks. - application has its own pool, -rapid fail detection is disabled - will try tracing logs (although another mystery is that there is no user activity on site when the crash happens for sometimes an hour, will it also trace what might go wrong in IIS?) I will look into the multi threaded code and stack overflows.

Comment: Could you explain what you see when the app pool crashes? Normally an app pool goes idle after 20 mins of inactivity, maybe it doesn't crash but has troubles booting up?

Comment: unfortunately IIS does not seem to notice a thing, everything looks normal, I just have to restart the pool. The pool does not go idle, because I have a uptime bot loading it every 5 min. Thanks

Comment: IIS may not notice something but i'm guessing someone notices something or this topic wouldn't exist? :) Is your bot receiving an error? Is your database logger not adding any records? Is the site giving a timeout? How do you perceive the "crashes"?